# Date time Format changes when updating a record in Classic ASP

Tags: sql, date, asp-classic, format

I'm hosting a site (Classic ASP) on an US based shared hosting, which uses a `MM/DD/YYYY` date format, and my site is using a `DD/MM/YYYY` format (EU format)

I added the following lines to every page:

```
Session.LCID = 1037
Response.LCID = 1037
```

to make sure that the format is right.

### **The problem**

I have a function that coverts strings to a `DD/MM/YYYY` format before inserting them to the DB.

When I update a date input on my DB, even though I insert:

**`06/09/2014`**

the data updated on the DB is:

**`09/06/2014`**

I'm using Access as a DB Engine.

**Note:**

This only happens when I update a record. When I insert a new record, it's fine.

Comment: 1037 looks like it's the LCID for Israel.  The code for the UK is 2057
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964664.aspx

Comment: I would suggest you change your function to pass the date to the database in a safer format like `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Comment: the LCID is Israel and it's fine - that's an Israeli site